# Python - Json data prints but also gives KeyError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to extract a specific key from JSON data pulled from multiple URLs, which i'm doing successfully, however, after the data prints i am for some reason getting a KeyError, which is confusing because the data is printing..... See code below;

```
for url in URLs:
    data = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False).json()
    notifications = data["notifications"]
    for notification in notifications:
        if notification["updates"].get("inDiscards", "outDiscards"):
            outDiscards = notification["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
            inDiscards = notification["updates"]["inDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
            print(outDiscards, inDiscards)
```

I am trying to pull the AVG float of InDiscards and OutDiscards

The json data is as follows:

```
{
 "notifications": [
  {
   "timestamp": "15002302302",
   "path_elements": [
    "Devices",
    "AAX1238128318",
    "versioned-data",
    "interfaces",
    "data",
    "Ethernet2",
    "aggregate",
    "rates",
    "1m"
   ],
 "updates": {
    "alignmentErrors": {
     "key": "alignmentErrors",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "inDiscards": {
     "key": "inDiscards",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
    "outDiscards": {
     "key": "outDiscards",
     "value": {
      "avg": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "max": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "min": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "stddev": {
       "float": 0
      },
      "weight": {
       "float": 1
      }
     }
    },
```

See the terminal output:

```
0 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 26, in <module>
    outDiscards = notification["updates"]["outDiscards"]["value"]["avg"]["float"]
KeyError: 'outDiscards'
```

as you can see the 0,0 prints correct but with the error

Comment: As @scott-hunter hunter was saying ... you get that error in one of the notifications that key is missing, you are iterating over those `notifications`, the first one is ok and you see the print, but the second/next one is missing the `outDiscards` in the `updates`. Try using a debugger next time or print the data and do a manual check, `KeyError` is not really a "stackoverflow question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notification["updates"].get("inDiscards", "outDiscards")` yields the value of `notification["updates"]["inDiscards"]` if it exists, and `"outDiscards"` otherwise, not (as you seem to assume) that *both* are present.

Comment: In what version of python you can check if some keys exist in a `dict` in that way?  ...
AFAIK the `notification["updates"].get("inDiscards", "outDiscards")` would give you the value for the key `"inDiscards"` if it exists or the string `"outDiscards"` as a "default value" if the key `"inDiscards"` is not present in the dict